# Thread safe makeUnique function for copy-on-write objects

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'd like to create a thread-safe copy-on-write object. I'd like to have a function `makeUnique`, which checks the reference counter: if it is 1, it does nothing. If it is not 1, then it clones the data. A basic non-thread-safe implementation could be this:

```
class COW {
    private:
        struct Data {
            int refCount;
            // various other members
        };
        Data *m_data;
    public:
        void makeUnique() {
            if (m_data->refCount!=1) {
                Data *newData = m_data->clone(); // returns a cloned data, with refCount==1
                decRef(m_data);
                m_data = newData;
            }
        }
};
```

Which is the most efficient way to make this thread-safe? I am targeting x86 and ARMv7+.

Basically, I think I need an atomic "compare-and-decrement" operation, which can be done with a compare-and-swap in a loop. Is there any more performant way to do this (considering my target platforms)?

Comment: I believe Sean Parent addresses this very issue in his [GN2013 talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Inheritance-Is-The-Base-Class-of-Evil). IIRC its COW using shared_ptr so it should be thread safe like you asked.

Comment: @Borgleader: thanks, I'll check it out. There are other interesting stuff here. I didn't know about this conference

Comment: @Borgleader: I think Sean addresses this issue in another [talk](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/Cpp-Seasoning).

Comment: actually in my link go to ~18:35 where he talks about the Photoshop history, I quote "the way we pulled this off is we said we're just going to make copies of the entire document but they're going to share stuff that's not modified"

Comment: @Borgleader: sure, it's related, but in his other talk there's some code which looks like mine. In the .pdf, it is page 45 (I haven't watched the talk yet, but I will). Thanks for this, interesting talks are here :)